# Ceiling light with push connector but 3 white wires in box

Tags: wiring

I just purchased a new ceiling light that uses push connectors rather than bare wires. My electrical box has a single black wire, and 3 white wires that are tied together. The old fixture's white was twisted into the 3 white wire connection. How should I work my light's connection - should I cut off the push connector and follow the previous method, or would there be a better approach?

Comment: Does the new light use stranded wire or solid wire to the push connectors?

Comment: What wiring arrangement produces one hot black wire and three neutral white wires in a box?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to *pigtail* the whites to the fixture's neutral connection with a short length of white wire that connects the bundle of whites to the connector.